# Bluetooth come and go - Toshiba Satellite C50D-A, Wifi Qualcomm Atheros QCWB335 (AR9565)

Tags: bluetooth, wacom, toshiba

Introducing myself as a novice-level linux user, I need your help to stabilize my beloved Toshiba laptop.

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop on my old laptop (Toshiba Satellite C50D-A).

I upgraded HDD to SSD, RAM to 8 GB and wifi PCI card to Qualcomm Atheros AR9565 (QCWB335) (support Bluetooth 4.0) because my old wifi card did not support Bluetooth technology.

- Qualcomm QCWB335 is compatible with Toshiba Satellite C50/C51 Series as C51 already equipped with QCWB335 from factory and C50 mainboard is same as C51 Series.

Anyway, Bluetooth was working perfectly from beginning and there were no issue for a while 1~2 weeks.
I connected many devices (BT Speaker, keyboard, mouse, and..... WACOM Intuos) as I love BT technology and hate something sticking out from machine.
Suddenly one day, BT could not connect WACOM Intuos to the machine. Device was detected but never paired.
And few days later, connection to keyboard becomes unstable, keeps coming and going, and even mouse reception gets poor, starts stuttering....

Then I decided to reinstall Ubuntu and everything worked fine thereafter......
Then those same symptoms coming again. BT repeats coming and going.

Maybe something corrupts BT driver (maybe because of WACOM?), I hardly believe the problem comes from Qualcomm device. FYI, I never tried to install any driver for devices manually. I updated through snapstore.

Anybody experienced same problem and willing to share your solution?